# Как написать сам метод для получения людей, и цикл, которые будет смотреть их online статус?

Tags: python, vkontakte-api

Делаю команду /members, которая будет выводить что-то следующее:

```
Количество участников в беседе: 3, из них онлайн онлайн: 2 #например

1. Петя Иванов (онлайн)
2. Иван Петров (оффлайн)
3. Пиван Итров (онлайн)
```

С количеством людей всё хорошо ('messages.getConversationMembers', {'peer_id': msg['peer_id'], 'fields': 'count'), но вот с онлайн не могу разобраться.
Можете, кому не сложно, написать сам метод для получения людей, и цикл, которые будет смотреть их online статус.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Удивительно, но *метод для получения людей* это [`users.get`](https://dev.vk.com/method/users.get) с дополнителным полем онлайна (`fields="online"`). Цикл писать не нужно, вы можете передавать несколько пользователей через запятую. Дальше обработка json в удобный формат.

---

Код писать не буду, поскольку реализация идеи будет отличаться в разных библиотеках.